# Cast object into object of another class when both implement same interface

Tags: c#

I have two classes (`CaseA` and `CaseB`) that both implement a common interface (`ICase`).  If I have an object of type `CaseA` is there a way to cast it into an object of type `CaseB`?

```
public class CaseA : ICase
{
    public string DocketNumber {get; set;}
    public DateTime FilingDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime? ArrestDate {get; set;}
    ...
    public IList<Offense> Offenses {get; set;} //Not part of ICase
}

public class CaseB : ICase, IOffense
{
   public string DocketNumber {get; set;}
   public DateTime FilingDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime? ArrestDate {get; set;}
   ...
   //Properties of IOffense
   public DateTime OffenseDate {get; set;}
   public string TrackingNumber {get; set;}
   public int OriginalSequenceNumber {get; set;}
}

public interface ICase {
   string DocketNumber {get; set;}
   DateTime FilingDate {get; set;}
   DateTime? ArrestDate {get; set;}
}

public interface IOffense {
    DateTime OffenseDate {get; set;}
    string TrackingNumber {get; set;}
    int OriginalSequenceNumber {get; set;}
}

//What I'd like to do
public IList<CaseA> ProcessData(List<CaseB> source)
{
    List<CaseA> results = new List<CaseA>();
    foreach(CaseB _item in source)
    {
       ICase _existing = _dbContext.ACases
           .FirstOrDefault(c => c.DocketNumber == _item.DocketNumber);

       if(_existing == null)
       {
           _existing = new CaseA();
           _existing = _item;
       }

       results.Add(_existing);
       IOffense offense = new Offense();
       offense = _item;
       ((CaseA)_existing).Offenses.Add(offense as Offense);
    }

   return results;
}
```

**Update**

Just to clarify some confusion as to why I'm doing this, I've added more to the classes to show you the issue I'm trying to resolve.

`CaseB` is kind of a flattened form of `CaseA` with a single offense instead of a List of Offenses.  I'm actually trying to map not just `CaseB` into `CaseA` but also `CaseB` as an Offense into `CaseA.Offenses`.

The use case is that I'm parsing a CSV file where each row contains not just Case information but also Offense information.  The CSV is read into the `CaseB` class and them I'm trying to parse them into my domain structure.

Thus, I can't necessarily treat everything as ICase because I also need access to Offenses.

Comment: If both implement ICase why not treat everything as that?

Comment: I'd use Automapper to map from one type of object to the other. Probably the best performance for this sort of thing, not too difficult to setup. https://automapper.org/

What is AutoMapper?
AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so why not invent a tool to do it for us?

Comment: If `_existing` is an entity you've just retrieved and you want to update it, simply assigning a new reference to the variable won't do it. You have to copy the properties over, or somehow tell EF to track the new instance as the same record.

Comment: @auburg I added a bit more detail that may help clarify

Comment: A `CaseA` object *isn't* a `CaseB` object, so no you can't cast one to be the other. You may be able to *convert* between them but it's up to you to implement the conversion operators that are required to deal with the *differences* between the two classes.

Comment: I think @madreflection hit on where I was going wrong.  I was viewing cast as "property copying" instead of assignment.  So what Damien_The_Unbeliever said makes sense in that the code is trying to assign an object of one type to an object of another type (which can't be done if their is no inheritance) as opposed to just copying common properties from one object to the other.  Thanks!